# Web Scraping Mahindra wesite

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to **scrape** the website "https://www.mahindrausa.com/map-hours-directions-tractors-utvs-farming-equipment--dealership--locate-a-dealer" to find their dealer's name, location, phone number etc. for each state in the US.

I am trying to use the beautiful soup library, however I am not able to find the items in `'li'` in the website. Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

page=requests.get('https://www.mahindrausa.com/map-hours-directions-tractors-utvs-farming-equipment--dealership--locate-a-dealer')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
a=soup.find('div',id="content")
b=a.find_all('h3',class_='lad__by-state--title')
lis=a.find_all('li')
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps some general advice, first:

You can check whether content is loaded dynamically by turning JavaScript off in your Browser's Inspection Tools. You will see that the data you are looking for is not loaded without JavaScript enabled. As BeautifulSoup cannot execute JavaScript, you won't be able to use it here.

Next, you would try to examine the Network Tab of your Browser's Inspection Tools and analyse the scripts that are loaded. If it's not directly clear which scripts are needed to load the data you are trying to scrape, block them (right clicking on the script). Block them until you find the script that is used to load the data. Here, you will quickly see that it's `locate-a-dealer.js`.

Open the script and try to find the functions that are used to load the data. I checked the DOM of the website and found that they use the `lad__`-prefix to populate the website, so I searched that term in the JavaScript file. I found a function that looked promising (`buildLeftList`) and followed it (looking which functions call `buildLeftList`) which is `buildMarkers` which again is called from `eqfeed_callback`. `eqfeed_callback`, however, is not called from within this file which seems like a dead end but notice the comment they put:

```
// generate markers from locations.js file
```

This sounds pretty promising! Let's see what this is: `locate-a-dealer` is stored at https://www.mahindrausa.com/js/locate-a-dealer.js?v=1.17d, so let's try looking at https://www.mahindrausa.com/js/locations.js.

Bingo! We can definitely parse that as a JSON and won't need to hassle with any any libraries.

Comment: I saved the file in json format and now when I try to read the file its throws me this error   raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

code:- data=json.load(open(filename.json))

Comment: You are absolutely right! This is not yet a JSON file so it's not possible to load it directly with the library. It is a JavaScript file with the definition of a variable (right at the beginning where it says `var jCollection`) and a function call at the end. You have to get the file (e.g. using a Session from the requests library `locations = session.get('https://www.mahindrausa.com/js/locations.js').text`) and then extract the JavaScript Object itself, either using some regex- or find-magic, or simply `locations[18:-31]`. Then use `json.loads` to parse the String.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a Selenium and chrome-driver for scraping